# React Native TypeError: Cannot read property 'backgroundVideo' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I just started learning React Native and I am having a tough time rendering a video in my app. Basically whats happening is that the same stylesheet that I have used for other parts of my code works for everything except when I use it for my video. I have no idea why that is....

Here is what I have done to solve this error:

1. I have npm install --save react-native-video
2. Ran react-native link (I don't think you need to do this anymore, but I did it just in case)
3. Checked to see if my spelling was correct....

This is my main code for the component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Button, StyleSheet, View, Text } from "react-native";
import LoginButton from "./LoginButton";
import { LoginPageStyle } from "../StyleSheet/LoginPageStyle";
import Video from "react-native-video";

export class LoginPage extends Component {
  super(props) {
    this.alertUser = this.alertUser.bind(this);
  }

  connectViaFacebook = () => {
    alert("Connecting To Facebook");
  };

  connectViaPhoneNumber = () => {
    alert("Connecting via phone number");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Video
          source={require("../Graphics/LoginVideo.mp4")}
          style={LoginPageStyle.backgroundVideo}
          muted={true}
          repeat={true}
          resizeMode={"cover"}
          rate={1.0}
          ignoreSilentSwitch={"obey"}
        />
        /> <Text style={LoginPageStyle.title}>Let's Hang</Text>
        <Text>Where people go on adventures</Text>
        <View style={LoginPageStyle.bottom}>
          <LoginButton
            text="Connect with Phone Number"
            onPress={this.connectViaPhoneNumber}
            color="#d10047"
          />

          <LoginButton
            text="Connect with Facebook"
            onPress={this.connectViaFacebook}
            color="#3B5998"
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default LoginPage;
```

And here is my style sheet...

```
import { StyleSheet, Dimensions } from "react-native";

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("window");

const LoginPageStyle = StyleSheet.create({
  title: {
    color: "green",
    fontSize: 60,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    marginTop: 60,
  },

  bottom: {
    paddingTop: 450,
  },

  backgroundVideo: {
    height: height,
    position: "absolute",
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    alignItems: "stretch",
    bottom: 0,
    right: 0,
  },
});

export default LoginPageStyle;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not named export inside LoginPageStyle.

So Change the import line

```
import { LoginPageStyle } from "../StyleSheet/LoginPageStyle";
```

To

```
import LoginPageStyle from "../StyleSheet/LoginPageStyle";
```

**OR**

Make it as named export inside LoginPageStyle

```
export default LoginPageStyle;
```

To

```
export { LoginPageStyle };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is in the way to export/import stylesheet. Not in the installed package. Try replacing your stylesheet with this one. Hope this helps.

```
import { StyleSheet, Dimensions } from "react-native";

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("window");

export const LoginPageStyle = StyleSheet.create({
  title: {
    color: "green",
    fontSize: 60,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    marginTop: 60,
  },

  bottom: {
    paddingTop: 450,
  },

  backgroundVideo: {
    height: height,
    position: "absolute",
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    alignItems: "stretch",
    bottom: 0,
    right: 0,
  },
});
```